# GetDlgItemInt( ) problem

Tags: c++, winapi

Ok, i have 2 edit controls and a button in my main window; in one edit control the user can write a number and when he push the button i read that number and i print it in the other edit control (which is read only).

My problem is that when i put a number and i press the button, for some reason that i dont understand i can get that number. And GetDlgItemInt() always return zero and his third parameter always return me false.

This is the code where i use GetDlgItemInt () to read the number:

```
            case CM_BUTTON:
                number = GetDlgItemInt(hwndEdit2, CM_EDIT2, &flag, FALSE); 
                if(flag)
                {
                    if(number > 0 && number < 20)
                    {
                        sprintf(message, "This is the number %d", number);
                        SetWindowText(hwndEdit, message);
                    }
                    else
                        MessageBox(hwnd, "Number to high or to low", "Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONWARNING);
                }
                else 
                    MessageBox(hwnd, "Error getting the number", "Error", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
                break;
```

Any suggest?

Comment: If you change your code to use `GetDlgItemText`, does it then return the text or would it still fail?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first parameter to `GetDlgItemInt` should be the handle to the *dialog box*. Unless the name `hwndEdit2` is *extremely* deceiving, you're currently passing the handle to the edit control itself instead.

Comment: Ok, i have test it and actually work when i use the correct handle (the handle of my main window); thanks for the help my friend.